# Intel D510MO board - 1000Mbit LAN or not?

Tags: motherboard, lan, specifications

The Intel forum seems to be down (signing in fails with connection refused), but perhaps someone here knows the answer.

The [Intel D510MO product page](http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/motherboards/D510MO/D510MO-overview.htm) says that the LAN is 10/100/1000, but when I look at [the NM10 chipset](http://www.intel.com/products/Internet_device/chipsets/NM10/NM10-overview.htm) it uses, it says it's just 10/100 (and the [detailed PDF spec here](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/322896.pdf) backs that up pretty definitively).

I don't immediately see anything saying the D510MO has a *different* LAN controller than the NM10's onboard one, and it would seem odd if it did given the purpose of the board (low power, small footprint; integrated).

Does this board support 1000Mbit LAN or not? Anyone have direct knowledge of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't immediately see anything saying the D510MO has a different LAN controller than the NM10's onboard one...

I didn't look hard enough, that's **exactly** what it's doing. The [detailed technical spec (PDF)](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18357/eng/D510MO_TechProdSpec.pdf) for the D510MO board says (in section 1.8) that it's using the Realtek 8111DL gigabit controller connected to the NM10's PCIe interface, not the LAN controller built into the NM10.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked at
My favourite local hardware supplier 
Localized (the Netherlands) Intel website
A few reviews

And they all say the board supports 10/100/1000 MBit lan
So I think you can be assured that it supports it fully

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, unless it was an in-depth review that actually tested (or at least checked) the 1000Mbit LAN feature, they're all probably just quoting Intel's specs page. This sort of thing does happen, the manufacturer misstates something (nearly always unintentionally) and "review" sites re-quote it without fact checking. Even the Tom's Hardware review completely ignores LAN.

Comment: So far I can find, it uses an unknown Realtek chip (can not find type etc.) for LAN which fully supports 10/100/1000